# Fetching distinct from mysql table is getting wrong result

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch distinct record from mysql table order by visit time which should be latest visit with below query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cookie_id, id, lead_id
FROM analytics where lead_id != 0 and user_id = 1
GROUP BY lead_id 
HAVING cookie_id > 1 order by visit_time desc
```

But with above query i am getting wrong result.

** My Required result initial:**

```
2054, 2016-02-02 14:19:40
2051, 2016-02-02 13:54:17
2055, 2016-02-02 12:22:16
2039, 2016-02-02 11:46:49
```

My original data table screen attached.from below table i am trying to get  filter result..

[image]

Comment: your required result shows two columns (_seems like "lead id" and "visit time"_), however your query is selecting three (_"cookie id", "id" and "lead id"_). Thats one reason why you are not getting the results you want.

Comment: Hi. Thanx for suggestion. But this is my sample that i want to get. Its very sort of required result i need.

Comment: Got it.. However you should provide the **exact** results you want, even if its just a sample, so that we can give you the right solution.

Comment: Ok. Can you solve the issue and generate a query for my table which will give me required result .. I appreciate. I tried my 4 hours and not getting success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was solution for me:

```
SELECT count(lead_id) as lead_id_count, lead_id, cookie_id, max(id) as max_id,max(visit_time)
FROM analytics where user_id =1 and lead_id != 0 GROUP BY cookie_id,lead_id HAVING lead_id_count > 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 ,10
```

Answer (score 2):

This does what you are looking for

```
select lead_id, cookie_id, max(visit_time) as visit_time
from analytics
where lead_id != 0
and user_id = 1
group by lead_id, cookie_id
order by visit_time desc
```

be sure that you have indexes on lead_id, user_id and visit_time

Answer (score 0):

you want GROUPWISE MAXIMUM of a column, an example exists in the manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Comment: Hi . thanx for you answer. I tried with after your ans but not getting wht is right query, i should try.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. For you to get your desired result(***the required result you mentioned above***). All you need to do is use `GROUP BY` like this:

```
SELECT lead_id, visit_time
FROM analytics
GROUP BY lead_id
```

**Sample SQL: [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72393/1)**